# Getting default 404 error page for unknown file extension even with custom 404 error page

Tags: iis-7.5

We have set a custom 404 error page in order to display a 'nice' page instead of the default IIS page.

When trying to access a non existing page with a known file extension (e.g. http://mydomain/dumb.aspx), the custom 404 page gets displayed.

When trying to access a file with an unknown file extension (e.g. http://mydomain/index.dumb), the default 404 error page gets displayed.

What puzzles me is that the IIS Web core is handling the error:

> ModuleName: IIS Web Core
>   Notification: 16
>   HttpStatus: 404 
>   HttpReason: Not Found
>   HttpSubStatus: 0
>   ErrorCode: 2147942402 
>   ConfigExceptionInfo : 
>   Notification: MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER 
>   ErrorCode: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002)

But the configured custom error page is note taken into account:

```
 <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/httpError" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

We do have handler mappings for * but not for *.* . Could it be the cause of the issue?
What would be the correct configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just had to change the errorMode attribute of the httpErrors node from Detailed to Custom.

From:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">
```

to:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
```

Answer (score 1):

I blogged about this. You probably are not setting your web.config correctly. Read my post to learn how to do it. You need this in your system.webserver node.

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

http://blog.aquabirdconsulting.com/2012/04/19/setting-up-asp-net-mvc-error-pages/

Comment: when adding the attribute you are mentioning, I do get an empty page instead of an error page.

The current httpErrors node we have is:
         <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/httpError" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>